# strange #define statements in C

Tags: c, embedded

I have an embedded C source code. In it's definitions, it has a lot of #define lines like following:

```
#define XNV_SPI_TX(x)               st(U1CSR &= 0xFD; U1DBUF = (x);)
```

any idea what does 
    st( ) 
means and does?
I am using IAR as compiler and toolchain.

Comment: By chance, is there a function called `st` that's `extern`-ed in one of the headers?

Comment: Since there's *statements* inside the `st` "call", it's most likely a macro too, search for it.

Comment: No. I searched the whole project files for "extern st" , it hasn't been defined anywhere.

Comment: I don't think anyone can give a better answer than what the first two comments have already guessed. Not unless you provide us the code base.

Comment: If you can't just let the IDE trace the identifier `st` for you, you need a better IDE.

Comment: With the IAR-IDE I am happy when I only have to restart the IDE just one or two times a day

Comment: You should ask the vendor. Or use a toolchain which has all source code available.

Comment: @jeb: You are using it wrong then. I haven't restarted IAR for years now ...

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to comments, here is what I found:

```
/* (The while condition below evaluates false without generating a
 *  constant-controlling-loop type of warning on most compilers.)
 */
#define st(x)      do { x } while (__LINE__ == -1)
```

Comment: That's pretty weird.  The standard idiom would be `do { x } while (0)`, which does not generate a warning on the compilers I use, even under fairly extreme warning options.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Plenty of compilers like to warn against "expression is always true", "expression is always false". Anyway, do while(0) macros are for garage hackers who don't have proper coding standards. If you always write braces after every single control/loop statement in your code, you'll not only save yourself from numerous classic bugs, but you also eliminate the need for obscure macros containing do while(0).

Comment: @Lundin: "Plenty" — would you care to mention some?  I've not seen it from GCC or Clang that I recall (even under some fairly stringent sets of warning options), but there are certainly other compilers around.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The whole line of Borland compilers used to do this (though apparently not the latest Embarcadero C++ Builder, just tested), as well as numerous embedded systems compilers, for example Freescale Codewarrior. Also [this one](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) which claims to be Visual C++ gives a warning.

Answer (score 1):

This construct is used to prevent if/else conditionals show unexpected behavior. 
For example if you have something like

```
#define assign() a=1;b=0;
```

it would not behave as expected in if/else statement.